# How to show the .Net Core Identity RazorPage somewhere other than its default location?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

.Net Core 6, MVC, and your basic authentication with Identity set up (which is RazorPages only), but I want my `Home/Index.cshtml` page to "host" the `Identity/Account/Login` page, preferably without having to resort to an iFrame.

Everything I've seen so far is simply how to build the Login page, but nothing on how to put the page somewhere besides its default location.

How do I put the Login form/page on my MVC Home/Index.cshtml page?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I put the Login form/page on my MVC Home/Index.cshtml page

Login page is a razor page not a partial view, so you cannot use   `<partial>` to  add Login page in the Index  view.  You can put your code for login in the Index.cshtml, but you may need change a lot, like building the Login page.

If you add  below code in the _layout, so that you can login at any view you want.

```
 <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
```

result:

[image]

Comment: ok - I did that and it doesn't change anything. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @NovaDev How about add `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />` in the _layout ?

Comment: that already is a thing. It shows the login link at the top. Also, it's not a razor page.

Comment: " Also, it's not a razor page." what do you mean? Do you mean this login link is ok or? Please have a look at [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) .

Comment: I have an MVC View and I want to put a razor page in it as a partial page. How do I do that?